# Adding table to existing map layer in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, arcgis-online

I have a map service that is published to a local ArcGIS Server. I've added it as a service to ArcGIS Online and added it to a map and made a lot of changes to the searching, pop-up's, etc. Later, I went back to the MXD and added a new table that is referenced by another layer. When I go back to the map in ArcGIS Online, it does not show the table I added. However, if I start a new map and add the service, the new table is picked up. How can I add that one table to the existing map without having to delete the layer and add it back? I really don't want to have to set up the map over again every time I need to add a layer.

Answer (score 1):

you need to override the existing service by re-sharing the service then use the overwrite option. That way the new service will include your newly added table.

Comment: I’ve already overwritten the service on the server with the new new table and I see it in the service definition. However, the new table is not showing up in the map on AGOL. I’m assuming it’s because I already added the service to the map but I can’t figure out a way to add the new table without deleting and re-adding the whole layer again which will cause me to lose a bunch of settings.

Comment: go to the layer properties in AGOL and set the refresh interval to ".1" , wait for it to refresh and see if it adds the table.

Comment: I tried changing that setting and the table still was not added.